# Getting Region Data of geolocation using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, geocode

Is there an easy way to determine a point's region in the world based on it's latitude and longitude?

I have an entry form that a user enters in their address (city, state, and country).  I then geocode this into a point that I can use on a Google Map.

However, I'd like to have it store the region of the point as well so I can use it for filtering the entry (North America, South America, Asia, Europe, Africa, Australia).

Is there a way to use the Google Maps API to determine the region of a geolocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**Google Geocoder**](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#KML) returns the `country`. Example:

```
     <Country>
      <CountryNameCode>US</CountryNameCode>
      <AdministrativeArea>
        <AdministrativeAreaName>CA</AdministrativeAreaName>
       <SubAdministrativeArea>
         <SubAdministrativeAreaName>Santa Clara</SubAdministrativeAreaName>
        ...
```

mapping countries to regions should be easy or easier to do.

Here is a list that would need some manual work:
[**Countries by region**](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/methods/m49/m49regin.htm)

You may find a pre-filled table with ISO code to region mappings with some searching.

Comment: So you don't think google provides the region data for a point?  I was hoping to make a simple javascript call to the api to determine the region.

Comment: Good idea but I'm not sure mapping countries to regions is trivial. I know I've sat through boring discussions about it.

Comment: The United Nations Statistical Division seems to have some sort of official classification: see http://unstats.un.org/unsd/methods/m49/m49regin.htm

Comment: I replaced the link in my answer with the UN one.

Comment: My programming skills are limited so I was hoping to have an easy solution.  My backup is to require the user to select their region, but that seems unnecessary if they've already entered in their country.

Comment: Mapping latitude / longitude to region is not going to be trivial, I'm afraid. Maybe some other Geocoding service can provide region data but if Google doesn't....

Comment: @proee: Re your 1st comment: One would think that Google could easily provide that information, but it doesn't seem that they do. There is a similar discussion on the Google Maps API forums http://groups.google.co.in/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/b6c21bf4e7a47394 with the same outcome.

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone...  This is my first post to stackoverflow and I'm amazed by the quick response.